# How to remove elements from a list by index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, filter

I am a python beginner. The data I am given in a text file(.txt) that contains my x and y values. x and y values are tab separated.

```
(x values)    (y values)
113           0
116           2
119           0
214           3
220           0
230           3
290           5
```

My task is to remove x and y values when y value is 0.

```
import numpy as np

files = ['my_data.txt']

for file in files:
    data = np.loadtxt(file,unpack=True)


y_value = data[1,0:]

y_list= list(y_value)

a= np.where(y_list==0)
b = str(a)
d= del.y_list(b)
```

What I attempted to do was to identify the indexes that contains zero and remove those elements based on indices. The given code doesn't seem to work. The error message says `d= del.y_list(b)` contains invalid syntax.

Could someone please explain what is going wrong with `d= del.y_list(b)`? Or alternatively, please feel free to share any other more efficient ways to accomplish the task.

(The code above describes removing zero elements from y only. I thought that if this works for y values I could recall x values using `data[0,0:]`.)

Comment: The syntax is `del ...`. Also, `y_list(b)` is not valid syntax. Why are you trying to do it?

Comment: This is not a list, but a `numpy` array...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler says that:

```
del.y_list(b)
```

Is **invalid syntax**. Usually one writes:

```
del variable
del variable[index]
del variable.attribute
```

To delete a variable, index, or attribute of that variable. Nevertheless I don't get why you make it that hard. You can simply write:

```
import numpy as np

files = ['my_data.txt']

for file in files:
    data = np.loadtxt(file,unpack=True)
    data_filtered = data[:,data[1,:] != 0]
```

Now `data_filtered` will contain a *numpy matrix* with only the rows where `y` is not equal to zero. This will be efficient and furthermore you can still perform all kinds of operations on that matrix since it is a numpy matrix.

For your sample input this generates:

```
>>> data[:,data[1,:] != 0]
array([[ 116.,  214.,  230.,  290.],
       [   2.,    3.,    3.,    5.]])
```

Comment: Dear Willem Van Onsem, I applied the code written above. I actually get only y value as an output for data[data[:,1] != 0].

Comment: But how is `data` structured? Is it a 2d matrix?

Comment: @user7852656: based on your question, I think you somehow transposed the data, does the edit works?

Comment: @user7852656: well, then the edit should probablywork.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `del` wrong. Instead, try the following:

```
result = []
with open('my_data.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not any([item == 0 for item in line.split()]):
            result.append(line)
    f.write(''.join(result))
```

Comment: @AJ UPPAL: the given code generates a list of x and y but it didn't really get rid of values that the y value is zero.